# word-vba: Unable to update linked image link

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a document with two inlineshapes into a table on the document header. These inlineshapes are linked images. The folder containing these images has moved and I'm unable to change the image link by VBA code.

I'm working with Word 2016. The documents were created on Word 2003. The only way to access the images has been exploring the table cells and finding the inlineshapes into them
The inlineshapes have no field object defined (nothing)
I can update the link manually going into the File menu > Edit File Links...

I would like to be able to change the image links with vba and not having to do it manually

Answer (score 0):

Well, at last I found what happened.

The images have to be accessed as inlineshapes, not as fields

the path to the image is stored in the property InlineShape.LinkFormat.SourceFullName

Changing this property value and then updating the inlineshape it worked

Sorry if I've bothered you but I think it can be helpful to other users